# Using specific columns, output rows that are present 3 times in a text file

Tags: sorting, awk, duplicates, compare

I have a text file and want to output rows where the first 4 columns appear exactly three times in the file.

```
chr1    1   A   T   sample1
chr1    3   G   C   sample1
chr2    1   G   C   sample1
chr2    2   T   A   sample1
chr3    4   T   A   sample1
chr1    1   A   T   sample2
chr2    3   T   A   sample2
chr3    4   T   A   sample2
chr1    1   A   T   sample3
chr2    1   G   C   sample3
chr3    4   T   A   sample3
chr1    1   A   T   sample4
chr2    1   G   C   sample4
chr5    1   A   T   sample4
chr5    2   G   C   sample4
```

If a row appears three times I want to add two columns for the other two samples that it appears in so the output from above would look like this:

```
chr2    1   G   C   sample1 sample3 sample4
chr3    4   T   A   sample1 sample2 sample3
```

I would do this in R but the file is too large to read in so I am looking for a solution that would work in linux. I have been looking into awk but cannot find anything for this exact situation.

The file is not currently sorted.

Thanks in advance!

edit: Thanks for all these informative answers. I selected the one that was most familiar to how I am used to working but the other answers look great too and I will learn from them.

Comment: Is that file tab-separated? How big is it (number of records)?

Comment: corrected example thanks. Yes its tab separated and both files have ~3 million lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash`, `tr` and `awk` assuming that input and output are tab-separated:

```
$ datamash -s -g1,2,3,4 collapse 5 < file | tr ',' '\t' | awk 'NF==7'
chr3    4       T       A       sample1 sample2 sample3
```

First, use `datamash` to sort the input file, group on the first four fields and collapse the values (comma-separated) on the 5th field.
The output would look like this:

```
$ datamash -s -g1,2,3,4  collapse 5 < file
chr1    1       A       T       sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4
chr1    3       G       C       sample1
chr2    1       G       C       sample1
chr2    2       G       C       sample3,sample4
chr2    2       T       A       sample1
chr2    3       T       A       sample2
chr3    4       T       A       sample1,sample2,sample3
chr5    1       A       T       sample4
chr5    2       G       C       sample4
```

Then pipe the output to `tr` to convert the commas to tabs and finally use `awk` to print the rows with seven fields.

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  {
    idx=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4
    cnt[idx]++
    data[idx]=(cnt[idx]==1 ? "" : data[idx] OFS) $5
  }
  END{
    for (i in cnt)
      if (cnt[i]==3) print i, data[i]
  }
' file
```

Maintain two arrays using the first four fields as index.
The first increments a counter whenever a record with the same index is encountered and the second appends the 5th field using a tab as separator.

In the end block, loop over the `cnt` array and print the index and the value of the `data` array if the count is three.

Answer (score 3):

For fun, a solution using [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) (Wrapped in a shell script that takes the data file as its only argument)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

file="$1"

# Consider loading your data into a persistent db if doing a lot of work
# on it, instead of a temporary one like this.
sqlite3 -batch -noheader <<EOF
.mode tabs
CREATE TEMP TABLE data(c1, c2 INTEGER, c3, c4, c5);
.import "$file" data
-- Not worth making an index for a one-off run, but for
-- repeated use would come in handy.
-- CREATE INDEX data_idx ON data(c1, c2, c3, c4);
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, group_concat(c5, char(9)/*tab*/)
FROM data
GROUP BY c1, c2, c3, c4
HAVING count(*) = 3
ORDER BY c1, c2, c3, c4;
EOF
```

Then:

```sh
$ ./demo.sh input.tsv
chr2    1   G   C   sample1 sample3 sample4
chr3    4   T   A   sample1 sample2 sample3
```

Comment: I'm not the efficient-est SQL programmer, so if anyone has any tips here, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: You can do it without the CTE and join, by using a `HAVING` clause, btw.

Comment: If you like, I can edit your answer to add the more efficient version? Or maybe add my own...

Comment: I encourage you to improve this answer. For my benefit of course but also for future readers being able to learn the best way.

Comment: @Shawn, I wish I could transfer ownership of this answer to you: this is way better that what I wrote.

Comment: Community wiki it? (Left to my own devices, I would have come up with the datamash approach first, though I am a fan of scripting sqlite).

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ curr = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }
curr != prev {
    prt()
    cnt = samples = ""
    prev = curr
}
{ samples = (cnt++ ? samples " " : "") $5 }
END { prt() }
function prt() { if ( cnt == 3 ) print prev samples }
```

.

```
$ sort -k1,4 file | awk -f tst.awk
chr2    1   G   C   sample1 sample3 sample4
chr3    4   T   A   sample1 sample2 sample3
```

`sort` uses paging etc. to handle input that's too large to fit in memory so it will successfully handle larger input than other tools can handle and the `awk` script is storing almost nothing in memory.